# Change variable text colour

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables, if-statement

I'm very new to this, so forgive me if I'm not saying this correctly.

I'm calling an API that gives the status of a train service. It displays the status as "Good Service, Minor Delays, Suspended etc)

I have it working, but I want to have an if else statement that says if Good service, then leave the font colour as is, but any else - make it a different colour. Below is the code I have

```
var statuswaterloo = value.lineStatuses[0].statusSeverityDescription;
console.log(statuswaterloo);

$('.statuswaterloo').text(statuswaterloo);

if (statuswaterloo = "Good Service") {} 

else {
color: red;
}
```

Comment: Use `==` instead of `=`. `==` is a [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators), and used to compare 2 or more values. Whereas `=` is an [Assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators), and used to set variables (e.g. `x = 5`)

Comment: Also the syntax that you have in your else block isn't quite correct. You need to do something along the lines of `$('.statuswaterloo').css('color', 'red');`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need if else, instead use negative comparison or `if not` syntax. Then use `!=` like this

```
if (statuswaterloo != "Good Service") {
  $('.statuswaterloo').css('color', 'red')
}
```

Comment: Unless I am missing something, I am not sure that syntax is correct. Looks like he is using jQuery, so it should probably be something like `$('.statuswaterloo').css('color', 'red');`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very nearly right. The main issue was just small syntactical problems.

Here is an alternative, and simpler approach you could consider. You can keep the first part of your code as it is

```js
$('.statusWaterloo:contains("Good Service")').css('color', 'green');
$('.statusWaterloo:contains("Severe Delays")').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="statusWaterloo">Good Service</p>
<p class="statusWaterloo">Severe Delays</p>
```

Looks like are already using jQuery, so you could just use [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) in the selector, and then update the styles that way.

Comment: Using "contains" here may have possible unintended side effect. How can you be sure what else is contained in the items with that class matcher? I think better to look for exact string match, no? For example what if div contains "Not Good Service", gotcha!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use an object literal to assign colors to possible states. Something like (didn't see jquery in your tags, so just JS).

```js
(() => {
  // literal to assign color to status
  const serviceStates = {
      "Good Service": "green",
      "Minor Delays": "orange",
      "Severe Delays": "red",
      "Suspended": "grey"
  };
  const statusElement = document.querySelector(".statuswaterloo");
  // method to fill and colorize based on status
  const setStatus = (statusElem, status) => {
    statusElem.textContent = status;
    statusElem.style.color = serviceStates[status];
  }
  
  // demo for given states
  setStatus(statusElement, "Good Service");
  setTimeout(() => setStatus(statusElement, "Minor Delays"), 2000);
  setTimeout(() => setStatus(statusElement, "Severe Delays"), 4000);
  setTimeout(() => setStatus(statusElement, "Suspended"), 6000);
  
})();
```

```html
<p class="statuswaterloo"></p>
```